# Unable to ajax request with meta_query

Tags: ajax, meta-query

I'm trying to ajax load specific posts using `meta_query`. but couldn't succeeded. my code is as following:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action','my_function');
//function
function my_function{
global $post;
$args = array (  
'post_type' => 'post',
            'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
            'suppress_filters' => true,
            'meta_query' => meta_args('my_meta_query_id' , $post->ID)
            ); 
    $pmt_pop = get_posts($args);
    foreach($pmt_pop as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
        the_title();
     endforeach;
  wp_reset_postdata();
    }



// meta_query argument
    function meta_args( $meta_key, $meta_value){
            return array(
                array(
                    'key' => $meta_key,
                    'value' => '"' . $meta_value . '";',
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => $meta_key,
                    'value' => ':' . $meta_value . ';',
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => $meta_key,
                    'value' => $meta_value,
                    'compare' => '=',
                ),
                'relation' => 'OR'
            );
        }
```

above code perfectly works without ajax calling eg: `echo my_function();` but it doesn't work on : eg: `//mydomain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=my_action` . 
if i remove `'meta_query' => meta_args('my_meta_qury_id' , $post->ID)`, it works on ajax request. 
Anybody has any idea? please help me to solve this issue, thanx.

Comment: There is no global $post in your Ajax request, you have to pass that to the query via JavaScript

Comment: There's lacking in your Ajax Request. You might forgot to put die();